# Vector on bisectrix between other two

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

Supose $\overrightarrow a=(2,-3,6)$ and $\overrightarrow b=(-1,2,-2)$ are represented in the same origin. Calculate the coordinates of the vector $\overrightarrow c$ that is on the bisectrix of the angle between $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$, knowing that $|\overrightarrow c|=3 \sqrt {42}$.

Comment: Normalize both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, then the mean of the normalized vectors is on the bisectrix. Normalize again and multiply by the given norm.

Comment: After I normalize I have to sum the two vectors?

Comment: Yes. You may divide by two, but actually sice you will normalize again afterwards, it's useless, so the sum is enough, I should have clarified this in my comment. Notice it's equivalent to what you do when you draw a bisectrix with compasses.

Comment: Ok thanks, going to try this now.

Comment: Solved, thanks again.